# Go language configuring

Tags: eclipse, git, go

I need to do a work for my university and I choose to do it using the Go language. Yesterday I installed the .msi and setted the variables to:

- GOPATH = `C:\Users\Gustavo\goprojects` (this is the folder that I want to place all my Go projects)
- GOROOT = `C:\Go\`
- PATH = `C:\Users\Gustavo\goprojects\bin`

After this, I installed the GoClipse plugin on my Eclipse and created a new project into the `goprojects` folder. Then, I created another folder in the `src` folder, and a .go file into this folder.

Now is my problem. When I started to write some code, everytime that I try to auto complete my code, Eclipse shows me an error and I was searching on google and found that I need to install one project from GitHub called `gocode`.

So I want to know where do I need to install it and how can I import it to my project.

P.S.: I am using Windows 8.1, I have git installed and the link of `gocode` project is: https://github.com/nsf/gocode

Comment: does `go get github.com/nsf/gocode` not work?

Comment: It works! But where should I use this? In exactly what folder should I download it? And how do I import to my .go file?

Comment: Setting GOROOT is cargo cult from the past. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem doing this steps:

- Downloaded the `gocode` to the `src` folder. (The path: `C:\Users\Gustavo\goprojects\src\github.com\nsf\gocode`)
- In the Eclipse, do this: Window -> Preferences.
- Open Go option in the left menu then click Tools.
- In the gocode path I set `C:\Users\Gustavo\goprojects\bin\gocode.exe`

And thats it! It works now.